# Generating random numbers with yield changes its values during debug mode

Tags: c#

I had a complex scenario when I was using a `yield` with random numbers and faced some strange behavior.

I tried to simplify my case with a simpler code example and managed to reproduce it with a very simple code.

In the following code, I would expect to get "Equal!" printed, but actually, it is not.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleAppSample
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> randomNumbers = GetRandomNumbers();
            int firstRandomnumber = randomNumbers.First();

            if (firstRandomnumber == randomNumbers.First())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal!");
            }
        }

        private static readonly Random random = new Random();
        private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
        public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                return random.Next(min, max);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomNumbers(int loopCount = 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
            {
                yield return RandomNumber(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug it and found even something weirder. While holding the breakpoint at the same place the values of the `randomNumbers` variable change every moment.

In the following image, you can see the watch shows different numbers for the same variable.

[image]

If I change the `GetRandomNumbers()` method implementation to insert values into a list and return the list (without using yield), it will work fine.

I try to understand why it works this way? I guess it is related to the way random generates numbers based on the computer clock and the way `yield` works, but I am not sure.

Comment: `new Random().Next()` is pretty bad idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Comment: I bet using a static class member `Random`, instead of instantiating in a tight loop, would `yield` a different result

Comment: @Sinatr I agree, I just used it for the example. It doesn't matter how you generate the number the issue still happens. I will update my question.

Comment: @maccettura The same issue happens with a static member.

Comment: Then it's another issue, since `IEnumerable<T>` is *lazy*.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049806/1997232).

Comment: yield Enumerables aka Iterators have a 'deferred execution'.
Each time the debugger fetches the data it gets different random numbers. Also when your code iterates the enumerable it executes the statement once again. Think of  a method using yield return as of a Lambda expression or Func that is executed every time it Enumerator is requested. Just the same as with a LINQ statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yield` means that the collection is not saved but essentially calculated when needed, namely each time you iterate the collection. Thus, each time `new Random().Next()` is called which may or may not give you a different result, depending on the time between those calls.

Thus, I would suggest the following changes:

1. If you want to see the same collection contents everytime, save the collection (for example, into a `List` as you suggested)
2. If you want to have multiple random numbers, keep the `Random` instance, if necessary in a static field. Creating a new instance will calculate a new seed based on the current system time and that may be the same, if you create two instances before Windows refreshes the system time.